# How to thread an anchored text frame in Indesign cs6

Tags: adobe-indesign

Like in the image attached below, I have original text on the left and translated text on the right. The translations need to be horizontally parallel to the original verses. I have anchored the translation text frames to the corresponding verse. But I cant thread the translation text frame when it is overset. Can you guys help me solve this or maybe go around this altogether?

I tried tables, It didnt work. The cells wont span on to the next page. Because some verses occupy more than one page.

Note: I want translation text frames anchored is mainly because, the document goes through frequent changes and all the text moves around. Even after moving, the verse and the translation should stay parallel to each other. The document has more than 100 pages at the moment.
[image: Illustration of the problem]

Comment: I don't think you can anchor to a linked text box like you are trying to do, which kind of makes sense.  If you have the text box linked to a line of text, and the line moves, if the anchor was split between two linked text boxes, it would make a nightmare of programming to keep everything in place.  The only way I can see from a functional stand point would be to have two columns of linked text boxes, and the anchor points are linked to the text lines in BOTH boxes.  But even that raises a lot of "how would this work" questions.  Maybe someone else with more experience with this has an idea.

Comment: Good question. This is a brain teaser. I'm inclined to say it's not really possible, but I'll think about it. InDesign is first and foremost a *design* tool and not always suited for authoring. My initial advice would be to finish the manuscript before you do the layout and then manually make sure the texts align using baseline grid and manual line breaks.

Comment: You cannot thread anchored frames. I don’t think there’s a good way to do this, unfortunately. The easiest way is probably to have two parallel sets of threaded frames and letting each text flow in each set – you’ll have to adjust spacing when the text changes, but at least the threading will work as expected and you’ll be able to have continuously selectable text in both languages if you export to PDF, for instance.